# Failed to create the directory, while creating directory in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, file

Well, I am getting this error, while I was trying to create a directory that does not exist, here is the code.

please let me know what I am missing in my code.

**here I have a function in a file called AccessFile.js**

```
  exports.writeFileToFolder = async (file, res, postId) => {
  const filePath = await `/images/${postId}/${file.name}`;
  // console.log("My postId", postId);
  file.mv(filePath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      // console.log("My filePath", filePath);
      res.json({ status: "ok", message: "File uploaded" });
    }
  });
};
```

**and I am using that function in another file called imageController.js**

```
 const saveUploadedFile = (res, files, postId) => {
  file = files.file;
  const dir = `/images/${postId}`;
  fs.access(dir, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      fs.mkdir(dir, (error2) => {
        if (error2) {
          res.status(500).send("Failed to create the directory!");
        } else {
          writeFileToFolder(file, res, postId);
        }
      });
      console.log("Directory does not exist.");
    } else {
      writeFileToFolder(file, res, postId);
      console.log("Directory exists.");
    }
  });
};
```

the error comes from this file, if you see I have a console.log in my code.

```
Failed to create the directory!
```

if anyone sees my mistakes please leave a comment.
thanks.
because it is a couple of hours that I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Could you show us the content of `error2` when `fs.mkdir` has failed

Comment: What do you mean by the content of the error2?

Comment: console.log(error2) it must contains a message and an errno

Comment: A potential problem could be that the `'/images/'` directory do not exists, in that case you should use `fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true }, () => { ... })`

Comment: Ah ok, so this error(Failed to create the directory!) is not displaying in the terminal, when I try to select an image and submit the form, then this error comes in the console network with code 500.
and in the terminal, it return this error

      console.log("Directory does not exist.");

Comment: Yep you are right, thanks a lot:)